# PKG_CONFIG_PATH does not clear

Tags: linux, path, pkg-config

I am experimenting with pkg-config.

> pkg-config --list-all

still shows a list of packages, even when PKG_CONFIG_PATH is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable is empty, then it uses the standard directory `/usr/share/pkgconfig` and `/usr/lib/<arch>/pkgconfig`.

Take a look on my example:

```
$ pkg-config  --debug 2>&1  | head
no output option set, defaulting to --exists
Error printing disabled by default due to use of output options --exists, --atleast/exact/max-version or no output option at all. Value of --print-errors: 0
Error printing disabled
Adding virtual 'pkg-config' package to list of known packages
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/share/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Scanning directory '/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/pkgconfig'
```